# Using Max and Count with a subquery

Tags: count, subquery, max

Database Table structure: Hotel(hotelNo, name, address) Room (roomNo, hotelNo, type, price) Booking(hotelNo, guestNo, dateFrom, dateTo, roomNo) Guest guestNo, name, address)

What is the most commonly booked room type for each hotel in London?

I have been told to join three tables, Room, Hotel and booking, and there will be a max and a count function and a subquery.

Comment: What the "Homework" tag is gone?

Comment: @user2337170, welcome to StackOverflow.  Can you make an attempt at solving this, and show us what you try?  That way we can give you better answers.